# Problem with search results page

Tags: search

After submitting the search form, the site directs to "homeurl/post-name/?s=lorem" instead of "homeurl/?s=lorem" when I have permalinks set to "%post-name%" ( not literally 'homeurl', but the domain of the site ).

When I have permalinks set to "/blog/%postname%", the search results url becomes /blog/%postname%/?s=lorem.

The action on the search form (searchform.php) is:

```
    <?php echo get_home_url(); ?>.
```

If I hard code it to the home url that won't work either. It keeps appending the search query after /blog or after the post name.

I even added the following to functions.php, and it had no effect:

```
 function search_url_rewrite () {
   if ( is_search() && !empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
     wp_redirect( home_url( '/search/' ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 
     's' ) ) );
    exit();
   }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', ' search_url_rewrite ' );
```

Any idea what might be going on here and what else I can try?
I already deactivated all plugins and tried it. Same story.

***** UPDATE (solution) *****

Because I am a very silly WordPresser, I had

```
  <?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

wrapped in form tags

```
  <form> </form>
```

I removed the tags and the problem stopped and search is working properly now.

Answer (score 0):

The form action should be this like below

```
action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

Comment: Also forgot to tell that remove the function that you added in functions.php to rewrite URL. This should work ..

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have changed the action to what you have suggested. However, I have found the real cause of the issue and it wasn't this.